# CodeIgniter 404 issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter. I created a forum but when I try to comment on an existing discussion I receive this error: `POST http://jaku0260.keaweb.dk//index.php/user/updatecomment 404 Not Found 165ms`.

On the same site you can actually [try for yourself](http://jaku0260.keaweb.dk/index.php/user):

User: jakub@mail.com

Pass: delfino

Here is the code for the form:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="<?php echo $post->postid;?>" placeholder="share your 

thoughts about this">
   <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="hello(<?php echo $post->postid;?>);"  

 type="button">Share</button>
 <script type="text/javascript">




function hello(id){

var data=document.getElementById(id).value;
if(data !=""){

var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "<?php echo base_url()?>/index.php/user/updatecomment";
var vars = "postid="+id+"&comment="+data;


hr.open("POST", url, true);
// Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
// Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;

        document.getElementById(id+"comment").innerHTML=    "<li style='list-style:none;margin-top: 10px;'><div class='row'><div class='col-lg-1'></div><div class='col-lg-10'><div class='input-group'><span class='input-group-btn'><img src='<?php echo base_url();?>assets/user/<?php echo $profpic;?>' class='commentboxpic'></span><span><span class='personnameclass'>Asad Ullah</span><span style='padding-left:5px;'>"+ data+"</span></span></div><!-- /input-group --></div><!-- /.col-lg-6 --></div><!-- /.row --></li>"+document.getElementById(id+"comment").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById(id).value="";         

    }
}
// Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
}

}

</script>
```

Here the function control:

```
    function updatecomment(){

if($this->session->userdata('userid')){
    $this->load->model('forum_model');
$id=$this->input->post('postid');

$userID=$this->session->userdata('userid');
$comment=$this->input->post('comment');

$this->forum_model->insertcomment($userID,$id,$comment);


   echo 1;
   }
    else{

echo 0;
     }
```

Model:

```
  function getkomments($id){
$this->db->where('forumid',$id);
$this->db->from('forumcomment');
$this->db->join('user','forumcomment.userid=user.userid');

$query=$this->db->get();
if($query->num_rows>=1)
    return $query->result();
return NULL;



 }

 function insertcomment($userID,$id,$comment){
$data=array(
    'userid'=>$userID,
    'forumid'=>$id,
    'comment'=>$comment

    );
$this->db->insert('forumcomment',$data);

return 1;

}
```

Thanks for help.

ajax:

```
function hello(id){

var data=document.getElementById(id).value;
if(data !=""){

var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
var url = "<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/user/updatecomment";
var vars = "postid="+id+"&comment="+data;


hr.open("POST", url, true);
// Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
// Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;

        document.getElementById(id+"comment").innerHTML=    "<li style='list-style:none; margin-top: 10px;'><div class='row'><div class='col-lg-1'></div><div class='col-lg-10'><div class='input-group'><span class='input-group-btn'><img src='<?php echo base_url();?>assets/user/5.jpg' class='commentboxpic'></span><span><span class='personnameclass'></span><span style='padding-left:5px;'>"+ data+"</span></span></div><!-- /input-group --></div><!-- /.col-lg-6 --></div><!-- /.row --></li>"+document.getElementById(id+"comment").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById(id).value="";         


    }
}
// Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the url is correct, maybe trying with this:

```
var url = "<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/user/updatecomment";
```

Also try to edit the .htaccess to remove the index.php, it will make easier pointing to a url and also will make it look better.

Comment: Thanks this help me but when I post the comment the name of the person what is posting is wrong is from another user. Can you help me with that?.

Comment: look if you're saving correctly your user id in session every time you login, also clear session variables when you logout, unset_userdata should work, if not, maybe you could try sending the user id through ajax, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks that help I check my ajax. I think I need to add the user in that ajax function.

Comment: it wouldn't be necessary to add the user with ajax since you already get the user when this login, but ajax would also work, glad to help! if my answer was helpful, can you please accept my answer? so I can make some reputation here :D

Comment: I try but without any success. You are able to change my ajax function in the correct way for see the correct name user?. Thanks for help.

Comment: @OmarHuanay **Since I am not an expert using codeigniter** and using `.htaccess` file to override `index.php`. What happens if I want to use that `URL` during an ajax call? should it work avoiding the `index.php` text or I must include it in order to make it work? *(just curious)*

Comment: Hej thanks. The code is above in the post now the system doesn't give me the possibility to repost so you can look in the post before. Again thanks.

Comment: @OscarJara And also since I'm not an codeigniter expert either, I think it shouldn't be working without the index.php into the full url, it may work if you give only the function name tho, overriding the htaccess will help to make it less confusing and look better in the url.

Comment: @kubuslemiszewwski I can't see any new code, can you edit your post?

Comment: Hey, you should get the user id variable and send it through your post request as a new parameter, then get it in your controller, also remove the userdata session.